# If $f:\Bbb{R}^{+}\to\Bbb{R}^n,\;t\mapsto f(t)=\Vert x(t)\Vert^2,$ then $f$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Assuming that $x:\Bbb{R}^{+}\to\Bbb{R}^n$ be differentiable. I want to prove that

\begin{align}f:\Bbb{R}^{+}\to\Bbb{R}\end{align}
\begin{align}t\mapsto f(t)=\Vert x(t)\Vert^2\end{align}
is differentiable and then, compute
\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\Vert x(t)\Vert^2\end{align}
where $\Vert x\Vert$ is the Euclidean.

**MY WORK**

I know that the answer is: 
\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\Vert x(t)\Vert^2=2\dot{x}\cdot x\end{align}
but I want to prove it. Nevertheless, I am thinking of using composition of functions and then use bilinearity. So, I have

\begin{align}k:\Bbb{R}^{+}\to\Bbb{R}^n\backslash {0}\times \Bbb{R} \end{align}
\begin{align}t\mapsto (x(t),\langle x(t),x(t)\rangle)\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}g:\Bbb{R}^n\backslash {0}\times \Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R} \end{align}
\begin{align}(x(t),\langle x(t),x(t)\rangle)\mapsto \Vert x(t)\Vert^2\end{align}
Then, $f=g\circ k$ so that \begin{align}f'(x)(k)=g'\left(h(x))(h'(x)k\right)\end{align}
\begin{align}=g'\left((x(t),\langle x(t),x(t)\rangle))(x'(t),2\Vert x(t)\Vert^2 x'(t)\right)\end{align}
\begin{align}=g\left((x(t),2 \langle x(t),x(t)\rangle x'(t)))+g(x'(t),\langle x(t),x(t)\rangle\right)\end{align}
Even with this approach of mine, I'm not seeing a way-through! Any help please?

Comment: I believe there are some typos since $\|x(t)\|^2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: However the idea is that $\|x(t)\|^2 = <x(t), x(t)>$ and use the use the bilinearity of the inner product.

Comment: @Alan Muniz: Oh, sorry! I've edited it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t understand why you use a complex map like $k$.

You can write $f=f_2\circ f_1$, where $f_1(t)=x(t)$ and $f_2: x \mapsto \Vert x \Vert^2 =\langle x,x \rangle$.

The Fréchet derivative of $f_2$ at $x$ is $f_2^\prime(x).u = 2 \langle x,u\rangle$ as $$\langle x+u,x+u\rangle = \langle x ,x \rangle+2\langle x,u\rangle +\langle u ,u \rangle$$

and $\lim\limits_{u \to 0} \dfrac{\langle u, u \rangle}{\Vert u \Vert}=0$.

Then applying the chain rule you get the result $f^\prime(t)= 2\langle x(t),x^\prime(t)\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm grateful!

Comment: Sorry, how did you apply that chain rule? I've been trying it to no avail!

Comment: \begin{align}f'(t)(k)=f'_{2}\left(f_1(t)\right)\left(f'_1(t)(k)\right)\end{align} \begin{align}=f'_{2}\left(x(t)\right)\left(x(t)(k)\right)\end{align}\begin{align}=2\langle x,k\rangle x'(t)(k)\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$f(t)=x_1(t)^2+x_2(t)^2+\cdots +x_n(t)^2\implies f'(t)=2(x_1(t)x_1'(t)+\cdots +x_n(t)x_n'(t))=2(x_1'(t),\dots, x_n'(t))\cdot (x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t))=2x'(t)\cdot x(t)=2\dot x\cdot x$, by the chain rule.